# Identity Server 4: Request Password Token Async with DB user

Tags: c#, database, identityserver4

I'm having some troubles understanding and making my app work with Identity Server 4. I want to generate a validation token using the users from Database. With TestUser everything is working, so I'm sure that I miss something.

I will start with my User model, I named it "ApplicationUser":

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
}
```

With this model class I made the User Register and the User Login.

```
    public async Task<ServiceResponse<int>> Register(ApplicationUser user, string password)
    {
        ServiceResponse<int> response = new ServiceResponse<int>();
        if (await UserExists(user.Email))
        {
            response.Success = false;
            response.Message = "User already exists.";
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            CreatePasswordHash(password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt);

            user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
            user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;
            user.UserName = user.Email;

            _context.ApplicationUsers.Add(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            response.Data = user.Id;
            return response;
        }
    }

    public async Task<ServiceResponse<string>> Login(string email, string password)
    {
        var response = new ServiceResponse<string>();
        var user = await _context.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Email.ToLower().Equals(email.ToLower()));
        if (user == null)
        {
            response.Success = false;
            response.Message = "User not found.";
        }
        else if (!VerifyPasswordHash(password, user.PasswordHash, user.PasswordSalt))
        {
            response.Success = false;
            response.Message = "Wrong password.";
        }
        else
        {
            response.Data = await CreateToken(email, password);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

The "CreateToken" method is where I request the token and it looks looks like this:

```
    private async Task<string> CreateToken(string username, string password)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:5001");

        if (disco.IsError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);
        }

        var tokenResponse = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
        {
            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,

            ClientId = "ro.client",
            ClientSecret = "SuperSecretPassword",

            UserName = username,
            Password = password,

            Scope = "task-app"
        });

        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Json);

        return tokenResponse.Json.ToString();
    }
```

And Startup.cs code for ConfigureServices is this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        var migrationAssembly = typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetName().Name;

        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(connectionString));

        //services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
        //    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly)));

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
                });
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
        });

        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Auth", Version = "v1" });
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("oath2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = "Standard Authorization header using the Bearer schema. Example: \"bearer {token}\"",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
            });
            c.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
        });


        services.AddIdentityServer()
            //Configuration Store: clients and resources
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseMySQL(connectionString, opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
            })
            //Oprerationals Store: tokens, consets, codes, etc
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseMySQL(connectionString, opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
            })
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();

    }
```

And finally my Config class for Identity Server is this:

```
    public static class Config
{
    public static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
    {
        return new List<TestUser>
        {
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "1",
                Username = "test1",
                Password = "123"
            },

            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "2",
                Username = "test2",
                Password = "123"
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources => new[]
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        new IdentityResource
        {
          Name = "role",
          UserClaims = new List<string> {"role"}
        }
    };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes => new[]
    {
        new ApiScope( "task-app" ),
    };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources => new[]
    {
        new ApiResource("task-app")
        {
            Scopes = new List<string> { "task-app" },
            ApiSecrets = new List<Secret> {new Secret("ScopeSecret".Sha256())},
            UserClaims = new List<string> { "role" }
        }
    };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients => new[]
    {
        new Client
        {
          ClientId = "ro.client",
          ClientName = "Client Credentials Client",

          AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
          ClientSecrets = {new Secret("SuperSecretPassword".Sha256())},

          AllowedScopes = { "task-app" }
        }
    };
}
```

The Register and Login methods are simple for a simple user. Do I need a custom implementation for Register and Login to work with Identity Server 4 ?

Do I miss something in my Config file or in the Startup class ?

Thank you very much for your time and your help !

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your context containing the Asp Net tables inside startup.cs:

```
var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(identityConnectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));
```

Comment: I have something like this:
` var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");`
 `var migrationAssembly = typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetName().Name;`

 `services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(connectionString));`

And If I put your code I get an Error at:  `services.AddIdentityServer()`. 
And the error is:  `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Service type: IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1 not registered.'`

I don't know what to do next. (PS sorry for too much edit. I didn't know how to format this comment)

Comment: If you're using a claims factory you'll have to add it to identity: .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<YourCustomFactory>()

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand. I edited my answer and I copied all the ConfigureServices method there. Is something that I miss in it ?